# Filter Google charts by lagenda items

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I've made a chart with Google Charts and I want to apply some filters.
I found out how to filter the graph by row (subjects in table underneath graph) but not by column (pete, john, carl, andrea) displayed in the legenda.

See my graph on jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fcqeA/

```
//Filtering subjects:
var compPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'control2',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Subject',
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': true
    }
  }
});
```

But now by legenda items...
I think I overlooked something but I really can't find it... i hope my question is clear

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way, thought there would be an easier way but maby not

```
// Place graph
var drawChart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind([compPicker], [chart, table]);;
drawChart.draw(data);

// Filter respondents
document.getElementById('names').onchange = function(evt) {
if (evt.target.selectedIndex == 0) {
  // Expectancy
  chart.setView({'columns': [0,1,2,3,4]});
  chart.setOption('colors', ["#FFC000","#00b0f0","#ff0000","#92d050"]);
} else if (evt.target.selectedIndex == 1) {
  chart.setView({'columns':  [0,1]});
  chart.setOption('colors', ["#FFC000"]);
} else if (evt.target.selectedIndex == 2) {
  chart.setView({'columns':  [0,2]});
  chart.setOption('colors', ["#00b0f0"]);
} else if (evt.target.selectedIndex == 3) {
  chart.setView({'columns':  [0,3]});
  chart.setOption('colors', ["#ff0000"]);
} else if (evt.target.selectedIndex == 4) {
  chart.setView({'columns':  [0,4]});
  chart.setOption('colors', ["#92d050"]);
} else {
   chart.setView({'columns': [0,1,2,3,4]});
  chart.setOption('colors', ["#FFC000","#00b0f0","#ff0000","#92d050"]);     
}
drawChart.draw(data);
};

<select id="names">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="pete">pete</option>
  <option value="john">john</option>
  <option value="carl">carl</option>
  <option value="andrea">andrea</option>
</select>
```

full code and example http://jsfiddle.net/fcqeA/1/